# jquery scroll up/down buttons not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make scroll up and down buttons on my site, but i must be missing something. here is my code...

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="middle-body">test</div>
    <div id="toTop">^</div>
    <div id="toBottom">^</div>
</body>
```

js/jquery:

```
var scrolled=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#toTop").on("click" ,function(){
        scrolled=scrolled+300;
        $("#middle-body").animate({
                scrollTop:  scrolled
        });
    });
    $("#toBottom").on("click" ,function(){
        scrolled=scrolled-300;
        $("#middle-body").animate({
                scrollTop:  scrolled
        });
    });
});
```

css:

```
#middle-body {
    color: white;
    background: #555;
    height: 900px;
}

#toTop {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: fixed;
    top: 40%;
    right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

#toBottom {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20%;
    right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

#toTop:hover, #toBottom:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

and last but not least the [fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/Lpetwnre/)
im still learning all this so im pretty green, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `middle-body` doesn't have anything to scroll, it's not restricted. You might be trying to scroll the body of your document.
- `scrollTop` is the number of pixels the top of the element's content is from the top of it's viewport. So when you want to go down the page, you add to it, not subtract:

```js
var scrolled=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#toTop").on("click" ,function(){
        scrolled=scrolled-300;
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop:  scrolled
        });
    });
    $("#toBottom").on("click" ,function(){
        scrolled=scrolled+300;
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop:  scrolled
        });
    });
});
```

```css
#middle-body {
    color: white;
    background: #555;
    height: 900px;
}

#toTop {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: fixed;
    top: 40%;
    right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

#toBottom {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20%;
    right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

#toTop:hover, #toBottom:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="middle-body">test</div>
    <div id="toTop">^</div>
    <div id="toBottom">^</div>
</body>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lpetwnre/9/)

Comment: You should also check each time after `scrolled` calculation it isn't less than zero (for up button) and it isn't greater than element[0].scrollHeight (for down button). Otherwise, when user continues to click on the same button when scroll reaches its logical end, `scrolled` goes and goes out of the element height borders and the opposite button will take visible affect only after several clicks, when `scrolled` will be again within element height borders.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#toTop").on("click" ,function(){
         $("html, body").animate({ 
          scrollTop: -300
        }, 600);
    });
    $("#toBottom").on("click" ,function(){
         $("html, body").animate({ 
          scrollTop: 300 
        }, 600);
    });
});
```

Here is an [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvcgar7g/)

Answer (score 0):

Your element is not an overflow element, while `html, body` is. http://jsfiddle.net/Lpetwnre/10/

```
$("#toTop, #toBottom").on("click" ,function(){
    var sc = this.id==="toTop" ? "-=200" : "+=200" ;
    $("html, body").stop().animate({scrollTop: sc });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, in addition to the other answers about animating `scrollTop` for `html,body`, it should be mentioned that you should have a cutoff range for incrementing and decrementing the `scrolled` value. You don't want it to go beyond the height of your `html` element (`document.documentElement.clientHeight`).  You also don't want it to go below `0`.